# Android Gradle project Sync Failed.Basic functionality will not work properly

Tags: android

I updated my android studio and my gradle will not sync 
issues it gives me these errors. Im also using firebase as for authorization and database.I have tried deleting the gradle files and rebuilding but that didnt work. any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
Failed to resolve .com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0
Failed to resolve com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
Failed to resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v4:25.3.1
Failed to resolve com.android.support:mediarouter-V7:25.2.0

here is the build gradle for the project

    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
here is my app gradle

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dude.sportspicks518"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.6'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: gradle generally points to exact error, can you check and post

Answer (score 1):

several way to try

1. Invalidate Cache/Restart AS
2. Clean Project and Rebuild
3. Update "Google Repository" and "Android Support repository" in the Android SDK Manager.

if not working, then If you are trying to get the support repository, this is the correct import:

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1"
```

If your compile api isn't 25, change the version to the latest with your compile api.

Android Studio should give you a yellow warning if you are using incompatible version. just hover it and use the suggestion given

P/s: Please please dont use `com.google.android.gms:play-services`.. it very heavy dex method count